# Facebook App Invite with Cordova-plugin-facebook4

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Facebook app invite with this plugin in my ionic application. The implemented codes are following as below:

```
$scope.appInviteToFriend = function(user){
      var url = "";      
      if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) 
      {
          url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.application";
      }
      else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) 
      {
          url = "https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/example-by-ionicapplication/id1983838444?l=en&mt=8";
      }

      var option = {
          url: url,
          picture : ""
      };

      facebookConnectPlugin.appInvite(
        option,
        function(obj){
            if(obj) {
                if(obj.completionGesture == "cancel") {
                    // user canceled, bad guy
                } else {
                    // user really invited someone :)
                }
            } else {
                // user just pressed done, bad guy
            }
        },
        function(obj){
            // error
            console.log(obj);
        }
    );
  }
```

When I executed these codes, the Facebook Invite Dialog opens and displayed app information correctly. But after click next button, select friend and also click send button, The error occurs. It says "Missing App Link URL. The app link used with this invite does not contain an Android or iOS URL.Developers are required to enter URl for at least one platform.". I've attached the error details with part of screenshot. Are these wrong the URLs which are store URL? How can I set the URLs?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an [App Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks) instead of a web URL. This link can be statically generated using Facebook's own tools, or you can generate them dynamically server-side. You can read more about these in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios#app_links).

Here's [a tutorial](http://pointdeveloper.com/adding-facebook-app-invite-for-cordova-and-phonegap-apps/) that walks through setting up an Android app.